# How in Javascript to esxclude from an Array of Objects the items which contain specific pair of keys and values

Tags: javascript

I created this snippet to understand the issue

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jakub41/rcx4eb1y/4/)

I'm trying with a filter to exclude from an array all the items which have 2 specific keys as `value === 'True'` and `team === 'Avengers'`.

```
characters.filter(character => character.team !== 'Avengers' && character.value !== 'True');
```

My goal is to see as a result the following Object

```
[{
  name: "Flash",
  team: "Justice League",
  value: "False"
}, {
  name: "Deadpool",
  team: "X-Force",
  value: "False"
}]
```

As you see I should not see any item which has `value === 'True'` and also all the items which have `team === 'Avengers'`

But from the fiddles, you see that I'm having a wrong result and I don't know how to fix this as there are 2 items that should be excluded because they have `value === true` but are not as you see below

```
[{
  name: "Flash",
  team: "Justice League",
  value: "False"
}, {
  name: "Deadpool",
  team: "X-Force",
  value: "False"
}, {
  name: "Deadpool",
  team: "X-Force",
  value: "true"
}, {
  name: "Deadpool",
  team: "X-Force",
  value: "true"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String comparison is case-sensitive: a string that equals `'True'` is not a string that equals `'true'`.

You can fix this by including both in your filter condition:

`character.team !== 'Avengers' && character.value !== 'True' && character.value !== 'true'`

or (what I would probably do since it’s more durable) convert the string to upper-case before comparing for a case-insensitive comparison:

`character.team.toUpperCase() !== 'AVENGERS' && character.value.toUpperCase() !== 'TRUE'`